# Hiding node.js implementation modules in exported closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules, information-hiding

I've got some "implementation" (private) modules in my node.js library, that I don't intend to be exported to any users of my library; however, it's `required` in index.js.

A simple example would be:

```
my_library/
|
|_ index.js
|
|_ private_module_1/
|  |
|  |_ index.js
|
|_ private_module_2/
   |
   |_ index.js
```

I don't want to distribute `private_module_1` or `private_module_2` publicly, just the source in `index.js`; but that code is dependent on the private modules.

Is there a common pattern or tool I can use to put/resolve dependencies in the top-level `index.js`, so that users of my library cannot access the private modules directly?

UPDATE (in response to Luke's comment below):

I'm thinking of dumping everything in the top-level index.js at build-time, and using the closure there - but I'd have to make sure to resolve the ordering/dependencies across modules manually, which seems like a pain.

To be clear, by "hiding", I don't mean minified/obfuscated code, just clean namespaces and APIs.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Why won't the closure pattern itself be sufficient? and 2. How "private" do you mean? You want obfuscated, impossible to find methods and values, or simply safe namespaces and clean APIs?

Comment: Hi Luke, clarified the above.